# 'Install app for SharePoint': Archive file cannot be size 0. deploying to office365

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, sharepoint-apps

I'm having an issue with deploying an app for Sharepoint (Sharepoint add-in) for my office 365 (Sharepoint) site collection. I can't deploy the app and the error says
 **"Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': Archive file cannot be size 0."** I checked with an empty project and issue still persists.

Same question on SP-stackexchange (not answered)
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/187607/error-occurred-in-deployment-step-install-sharepoint-add-in-archive-file-cann

Comment: We're having the same issue.
What we already tried: Changing site collections, repairing & re-installing Visual Studio, cleaning and rebuilding the solution.
Does anybody know what and where the archive file is?

Comment: Me too, having same problem, created a new dev account for office 365, new site collection, new SP add-in using visual studio, and another time using NAPA, all same result "Archive file cannot be size 0."